# Query Error : get_complied_select Not working Properly?

Tags: mysql, query-builder

I have a code below ...

```
$subQuery = $this->db->select('postid')
->from('sp_tag_tbl')
->where("find_in_set('"  . $userid . "', userid) <> 0")
->get_compiled_select();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($subQuery); exit;
```

the get_compiled_select embedding `\n` that is creating error while using it as a sub query in another query. Please let me know the correct way to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\n` was embedded due to the `Codeigniter` query formatting. We need to pass `FALSE` as a third parameter to stop formatting.